# Why isn't my GA4 receiving data from my subdomains?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have a GA4 property that is receiving data from my website, let's call it example.com.
I now have two subdomains (register.example.com and purchase.example.com). Both subdomains are pointing to the same GA4 property. However, I'm not receiving any data. If in GA4 I go to Engagement > Pages and Screens and filter by the domain name, they don't show up. Any thoughts?